# How do I create a text file from a multiple of other text files?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, filereader, filewriter

I need to create a textfile that combines any numbers of textfiles from the same folder. They need to be accessed via the arguments in my main-method, so that it look for the filenames I write. The last file name should be the destination file.
So far my code is creating a new file that has the last string I enter as a name, but it is an empty file. I suspect that my `BufferedReader` class is not doing what it should, but I'm at a loss. Here is my code. First a driver class and the the actual program. Thanks so much for any help you're able to provide!

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CatFiles cat = new CatFiles(args);
        cat.bookCombiner();

}
}
```

This is where it goes wrong.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CatFiles {
    private String[] files;

public CatFiles(String[] files) {
    this.files = files;
}

public String getDest() {

    String destination = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        destination = files[i];
    }

    return destination;
}

public void bookCombiner() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(getDest());
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length - 1; i++) {
            File file = new File(files[i]);
            String line = null;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(files.length - 1);
            }

        }
        writer.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try{
            reader.close();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- You are using `if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)` instead of while which will just write the file length - 1 once into target file.
- You are using `writer.write(files.length - 1);` to write to last file, which should be `writer.write(line);`

Comment: That did it! Only thing I now need is to keep the formatting of the original files. Any clue how to do that?

Comment: so while writing, you could make use of say tab \t, new line \n. So lets say if you want to add new line you could do like writer.write(line + "\n"); Btw that's a follow up question. Hope it helped. Please accept the answer if it has helped you so we could close this question.

Answer (score 1):

you never use writer to write line. Change:

```
if ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     writer.write(files.length - 1);
}
```

to

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    writer.write(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to Java! Now it makes a new .txt with the strings I entered as content. But I somehow need to make those strings into paths to other .txt files. Hope you are able to help.

Comment: create fileWriter like this new FileWriter(getDest(), true) that means you want to append to file, instead of overwriting it

Answer (score 0):

You have probably an error in your getDest() method. Now it just returns last element from files[] array. It is equivalent to:

```
return files[files.length - 1];
```